# too many declaration of a construct match this call

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have declared an  object with a constructor that takes 2 arguments. I can't use it because oracle returns:

> [Error] Execution (2: 10): ORA-06553: PLS-307: too many declarations
> of 'BOUNDARY' match this call

- I haven't declared this constructor more than one time.
- My code is working on [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=46560e2363186292813201a6efb45a3f) but not on my database. The only difference between the code on dbfiddle and my code is that this object has an owner.
- Therefore the name of the object is defined this way: `owner_name.object_name`.
- I have checked if the object is defined in another owner. And when I call the constructor I use `owner_name.constructor`.
- I've created a dummy constructor that take 0 arguments and it works.

_

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_user.boundary AS OBJECT
(
    v_start INTEGER,
    v_end INTEGER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary (i_start INTEGER, i_end INTEGER)
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    MEMBER FUNCTION isInside (i INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY my_user.boundary
AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary 
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    IS
    BEGIN
        v_start := 1;
        v_end := 2;
        RETURN;
    END;
    
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary (i_start INTEGER, i_end INTEGER)
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    IS
    BEGIN
        v_start := i_start;
        v_end := i_end;
        RETURN;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION isInside (i INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
    IS
    BEGIN
        IF v_start <= i AND i <= v_end
        THEN
            RETURN 1;
        ELSE
            RETURN 0;
        END IF;
    END;
END;

SELECT ( my_user.boundary(1,2)) FROM DUAL; --doesn't work
```

> [Error] Execution (2: 10): ORA-06553: PLS-307: too many declarations of 'BOUNDARY' match this call

```
SELECT ( my_user.boundary()).isInside(1) FROM DUAL; --is working
```

> 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in db<>fiddle when run [under Oracle 21c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=46560e2363186292813201a6efb45a3f), but [not under 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46560e2363186292813201a6efb45a3f) or 11g.

You said you haven't declared the constructor more than once, but you sort of have; there is a default constructor with the same parameters - [from the 19c doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html):

> The database implicitly defines a constructor method for each user-defined type that you create. A constructor is a system-supplied procedure that is used in SQL statements or in PL/SQL code to construct an instance of the type value. The name of the constructor method is the name of the user-defined type. You can also create a user-defined constructor using the constructor_spec syntax.

[and](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/object-methods.html#GUID-52304F42-33D7-423E-9CB2-7641FAA25D52):

> By default, the system implicitly defines a constructor function for all object types that have attributes.
>
> A system-defined constructor is sometimes known as the attribute value constructor.

You are creating a user-defined constructor, but it has the same definition as the implicit one. Well, almost.

19c [also says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/system-defined-and-user-defined-constructors.html#GUID-50C1ADD6-F597-4C6F-BC08-F5DC193F2257):

> a user-defined constructor does hide, and thus supersede, the attribute-value constructor for its type if the signature of the user-defined constructor exactly matches the signature of the attribute-value constructor.
>
> For the signatures to match, the names and types of the parameters (after the implicit SELF parameter) of the user-defined constructor must be the same as the names and types of the attributes of the type.

In 18c [it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ec19d508c2ab94331218f2fe02397bc) if you change the parameter *names* to match the attribute names:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE boundary AS OBJECT
(
    v_start INTEGER,
    v_end INTEGER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary (v_start INTEGER, v_end INTEGER)
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    MEMBER FUNCTION isInside (i INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY boundary
AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary (v_start INTEGER, v_end INTEGER)
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.v_start := v_start;
        SELF.v_end := v_end;
        RETURN;
    END;
...
```

21c seems to be more forgiving/flexible, though the documentation [hasn't changed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adobj/system-defined-and-user-defined-constructors.html). (Or maybe 19c, or some version of it, also allows this - I'm just going on the available versions in db<>fiddle..)

However, as all you are doing here is a simple assignment, you don't need your overriding constructor in any version - [it works without it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4a25b031b2059ea2daf2261c92ce0640).

Answer (score 0):

After I added the undeclared constructor to the spec it compiled and worked fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BV_OWN.boundary AS OBJECT
(
    v_start INTEGER,
    v_end INTEGER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary   -- added
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION boundary (i_start INTEGER, i_end INTEGER)
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    MEMBER FUNCTION isInside (i INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
);
```

Had to drop the schema specs since I didn't have a BV_OWN user to test with. Used Oracle 21c. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=67d6b844d9dec906278840576efe79ce)

Comment: Like the db<>fiddle the OP linked to in the question, this works in 21c [but not in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=67d6b844d9dec906278840576efe79ce).